# openvpn optimizations for Low bandwidth (250mb a month)

Tags: openvpn, bandwidth, compression, openwrt

I am using openwrt lede with a lte stick 250-300mb a month depending on the unit so preferably hitting 250 or lower would be better for the entire system these are the clients the server doesn't have a cap like that it seems we are hitting about 10-20mb a day all that runs on it is a telnet session that sends and receives 2mb total so i am assuming the other data is from openvpn.

Would compression be the best idea for this? If so is their much to setup other than adding compress lzo to both the server and client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following to decerase traffic for the connection:

1. use a `UDP`-connection, requires less packets because it does not double-encapsulate TCP communications
2. use `comp-lzo` as you suggested
3. configure `keepalive` on to high values to still maintain a permanent connection but decrease keepalive datagrams greatly. I guess this is your main traffic generator in the background
4. after configuring keepalive, use further directives like `--persist-tun, --persist-key, --persist-local-ip, --persist-remote-ip` to further decrease negotiation traffic.

You have to configure all the directives on both sides - server and client of course.

See https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/69-openvpn-21.html for a documentation of the config options.